# C++ - No matching function for call to 'getline'

Tags: c++, syntax, parameters, getline

I cannot figure out the proper syntax for a file istream getline() call

I've tried so many variations of calling `getline()` with all different kinds of parameters and after looking at several different pieces of documentation and it just won't work.

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt");
char tmp;
std::getline(tmp, in);
```

This one results in

```
../directory/file.cpp:178:2: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
    std::getline(tmp, in);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But other documentation says

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt");
char tmp;
in.getline(tmp);
```

which also spits out

```
../directory/file.cpp:179:5: error: no matching member function for call to
  'getline'
    in.getline(tmp);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

All I need to do is read a file line by line and I can't figure it out. Could someone please point me in the right direction? I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Did you check the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: Personally, when I have an issue with function syntax, [**I look up the syntax online**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  You should be using the function form for `std::string`.

Comment: @EdChum I've referenced this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ checking your resource now

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes this would be easier if I could use std::string but the underlying problem is that this is for my Data Structures course and I have to build my own string. so this is me trying to overload the input operator for my homemade data type

Comment: @conjenks That page doesn't mention any overload that takes a single `char` as the destination parameter. (There is none because reading a whole line into one character doesn't make sense.) Since this is coursework, you should have covered the concept of pointers by now, and probably recently.

Comment: You will have to read one character at a time using `istream.get()`.  If the character is not a newline or the delimiter append to the string.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I should be passing a char* not just a char, I think that may have solved my problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

getline() reads string, but you pass it a single char.

Use it like this:

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt");
std::string tmp;
std::getline(in, tmp);
```